# PyCharm SSH interpreter GCP VM

Tags: ssh, pycharm

I'm trying to set up the SSH interpreter with PyCharm on Windows. I have a VM on Google Cloud Platform, I've generated private/public keys with puttyGen and I can establish a connection with putty.

However, I can't SSH with PyCharm pro even though I use the same settings (private key and public IP from the VM).

Any ideas why>?

Comment: 1) Did you install the public key on the VM? 2) What is the error message? Edit your question with details.

Comment: You might also want to consider checking this documentation about [Bastion host](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#bastion) on GCE and its [advance methods](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#bastion_host)

Comment: I've found the solution. I put my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.
The problem is that PyCharm doesn't support the file format generated by Putty. I've just ended up generating the key with linux.